# Maven - Using the Assembly plugin to package dependencies from multiple projects into one file

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I’m working on a project that is made up of multiple other projects. It has the following structure:

```
MainProject

  --projectA

  --projectB

  --projectC

  --projectD

  --parent

  --projectE

  ...

  --projectX
```

As you can see the parent is amongst the others. I’m not sure if this is unusual or not but it is the way it is and I have to just work with it.

I’m looking to use the Assembly plugin to get the dependencies from each of the sub projects and zip them up all within one folder. So for example, I want a zip file containing a folder which contains all of the unpacked dependencies of the children projects.

This is what I have so far:

assembly.xml (this is in the parent project)

```
[...]
    <id>package</id>
        <formats>
            <format>zip</format>
        </formats>
        <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

        <moduleSets>
             <moduleSet>
             <includes>
                 <include>com.example:../one</include>
                 <include>com.example2:../two</include>
                 <include>com.exampleX:../three</include>
             </includes>
             <binaries>
                 <outputDirectory>/library/jars</outputDirectory>
                 <unpack>false</unpack>
             </binaries>
             </moduleSet>
        </moduleSets>

        <dependencySets>
            <dependencySet>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <outputDirectory>library/jars</outputDirectory>
             </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>
        <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

and this is in the parent `pom.xml`

```
[...]
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>assembly</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
        <configuration>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
[...]
```

When I run a `mvn clean install` from cmd the build is successful. It does not however create a zip file containing my `library/jars` directory which should then contain all of the dependencies from each of the projects. It simply creates zips in each project. These zips do not contain the directory I want or any dependencies, they are simply zips of the each project directory. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, please add details on the projects relations to each other? Dependencies, modules sections etc.